# Query to select data that have only 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i just have the table with data like this

```
    ID       PHONE_NUMBER          VERSION         VERSION_NAME
   --------------------------------------------------------------
     1       86578900000              0               3.4.2
     2       86578900000              1               3.4.2.1
     3       899589023200             0               3.4.2
     4       878999933336             0               3.4.2
     5       82199987629              0               3.4.2
     6       82199987629              1               3.4.2.1
     7       888729203892             0               3.4.2.1
```

So, i would like to have the data for phone number that count only have 1 row and version_name is 3.4.2 is like this :

```
        ID       PHONE_NUMBER        
   -----------------------------
     3           899589023200             
     4           878999933336
```

I run query

```
Select PHONE_NUMBER from TABLE_C where VERSION_NAME = '3.4.2' group by PHONE_NUMBER having count(b.PHONE_NUMBER) = 1
```

but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Please [edit] the question and explain what "doesn't work as expected" means. Do you get an error? Do you get phone numbers that have bad counts? Also, why the [tag:java] tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method where you are first getting the phone numbers which have one and only one appearance in the table and then you are comparing that data with phone numbers that are in version 3.4.2 . For e.g. Phone number 899589023200 will be a row in ph_count as the count is 1 and then 899589023200 also is in version 3.4.2 so when joined we get it in the output.

[image]

```
with test (id, phone_number, version_name) as
     (select 1, 86578900000 , '3.4.2'   union 
      select 2, 86578900000 , '3.4.2.1' union 
      select 3, 899589023200, '3.4.2'   union 
      select 4, 878999933336, '3.4.2'   union 
      select 5, 82199987629 , '3.4.2'   union 
      select 6, 82199987629 , '3.4.2.1' union 
      select 7, 888729203892, '3.4.2.1' 
     )

SELECT t.*
FROM test t
JOIN (SELECT phone_number, COUNT(*) as ph_count
      FROM 
      test t
      GROUP BY phone_number
      HAVING count(*) = 1) ph_cnt ON ph_cnt.phone_number = t.phone_number
WHERE t.version_name like '3.4.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (id, phone_number, version_name) as
  2    (select 1, 86578900000 , '3.4.2'   from dual union all
  3     select 2, 86578900000 , '3.4.2.1' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 899589023200, '3.4.2'   from dual union all
  5     select 4, 878999933336, '3.4.2'   from dual union all
  6     select 5, 82199987629 , '3.4.2'   from dual union all
  7     select 6, 82199987629 , '3.4.2.1' from dual union all
  8     select 7, 888729203892, '3.4.2.1' from dual
  9    )
 10  select a.id,
 11         a.phone_number
 12  from test a
 13  where a.version_name = '3.4.2'
 14    and a.phone_number in (select b.phone_number
 15                           from test b
 16                           group by b.phone_number
 17                           having count(*) = 1
 18                          );

        ID  PHONE_NUMBER
---------- -------------
         3  899589023200
         4  878999933336

SQL>
```

Condition in line #13 fetches only `3.4.2` version name, while subquery (lines #14 - 18) makes sure that phone numbers have only one appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it should work...

```
Select PHONE_NUMBER from TABLE_C where VERSION_NAME = '3.4.2' group by VERSION_NAME
having count(b.PHONE_NUMBER) = 1
```

Comment: I don't think so, because it counts only phone numbers whose version name is 3.4.2. but - as far as I understood - you should check **all** phone numbers, regardless version name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.phone_number = t.phone_number and
                        t2.version <> '3.4.2'
                 );
```

You can literally describe this query as:  "Return all rows where the same phone number has no version other than `'3.4.2'`".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `WINDOWS` function as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*,
       sum(case when version_name = '3.4.2' then 1 end) over (partition by phone_number ) as sm,
       count(1) over (partition by phone_number ) as cnt
from your_table T)
where cnt = 1 and sm = 1
```